# What is wrong with my firefox browser test?

Tags: javascript

I want to test if the user is using Firefox under version 3.0, if yes trigger the function and here's what I ended up with! Now I use the version 14.0 of Firefox to test it out and it still trigger the function! Anyone can help a beginner? Thanks!

script:

```
if (/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)){ //test for Firefox/x.x or Firefox x.x (ignoring remaining digits);
var ffversion= Number(RegExp.$1) // capture x.x portion and store as a number
if (ffversion<=3)
{
```

Comment: Oh, you again! ... Wait, who are you? `:P`

Comment: Haha i jsut asked a question in javascript like 10 minuts ago because i cant find any specific answers and i have a hard time figuring answers myself because in new to javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do it in one regex test:

```
if(/Firefox[\/\s]([0-2]\.|3\.0)/g.test(navigator.userAgent)){
  // do old FF stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
var result = /Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.exec( navigator.userAgent );

if ( result && +result[1] <= 3 ) {
    // do your thing 
}
```

Note that feature testing would make a better solution:

```
if ( browser_doesnt_implement_this_feature ) {
    implementIt();
}
```

Comment: its just a backup in case that some one is still using a realy old vertion of firefox, to replace a svg with a png... I don't want to test anything just check what vertion you are on I think it's lighter.